# Getting 404 Error while trying to access file on laravel 8

Tags: php, filesystems, http-status-code-404, laravel-8, ubuntu-server

Hi i am trying to access a file on a server via link eg (https://domain.name/storage/images/Image_logo.png) but i get the laravel 404 error screen.

I can access the file on my local machine via (127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/Image_logo.png).

Things i did

1. Make sure i have the files on the server on the same laravel directory as the one on my local machine
2. ran `php artisan storage:link` on both the server and local machine

Is there something i need to configure on the server to be able to get the file?
the server is an ubuntu based server.

Comment: Check is there `images` folder created in public folder?

Comment: in the public folder there is a symlink for 'storage' which images is in

Comment: Check public folder permission.

Comment: its says **owner permissions** :read, write, execute  **Group permissions** : read, execute    **Public permissions** : read, execute

Comment: Is file exists in `public/storage/images/Image_logo.png`?

Comment: yes it does exist, just verified again

Comment: Problem is something else. Are you able to access your project with url?

Comment: Check your `.env` file for `APP_URL`, have correct domain name.

Comment: i am able to run the functions  off the urls and `APP_URL ` is correct

Comment: Could it have something to do with Apache not following symbolic links? You could perhaps play with `Options FollowSymLinks` in the server config or in a `.htaccess` file. Or could it be due to a `RewriteRule` which changes the URL internally, leading to a 404?